# Call of Duty Warzone just never launched for me since 2020 April. How to get help and support?

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-warzone

So as some of the Warzone player would know, they implemented some change which made it to the news that it won't launch from the battlenet. I've tried restart, reinstall and all of the methods i've seen online has failed.

I can see some people are back in the game now but i don't know the best way to get help as they don't have a way to email contacting them. the Online chat option is always disabled and i'm stuck.

Blizzard on the other hand couldn't support me with non-blizzard game so I couldn't get help from their side either. What's the issue? I'm running a 3090 and as soon as I hit launch, it will fail and nothing happens.

Comment: I think we would need more information to answer this. If it crashes there must be a crash log. If it doesn't even open anything there must be something wrong with your OS. Anyway, if I were you, I would just clean install the OS and see what happens. I admire your patience that you've waited for an year and 8 month just to play the warzone.

Comment: Sorry did you say “April 2020” as in, almost 2 years ago?

Comment: actually i think it fixed itself now. I tried this about a month ago and nothing happend. they must have done something. sorry guys. I should've gave it one last try before opening up a question